# Ascertain the method of file upload in SharePoint 2013 document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, event-handlers, drag-and-drop

In an ItemAdded event receiver, is there a way to ascertain whether the file was uploaded via the "new item" button in the document library or whether it was dragged and dropped into the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

In 2013 there are only 3 way to upload document in library.
1) Using New Item link.
2) Via drag and drop.
3) Open library using Window explorer.

Note:- Link to upload multiple item in library was removed in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesnt answer my question re ItemAdded event receiver.